# AngularJS issue not showing output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.4.8
I was having a list in controller. It is connected to a module.
and referring it in my html doesn't show list of activities

## folder structure: app/sorting.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<body ng-controller="MyC">

    <div>
    Filter it on: <input type="text" ng-model="filteron.aname" />
    <table>
    <TR>
        <TD>Activity Id </TD>   
        <TD> Sbprocess Name </TD>   
        <TD> Activity Name </TD>  
        <TD> Cost </TD>
    </TR>
        <TR ng-repeat="activity in activities | filter:filteron">
            <TD>{{activity.activityid}}</TD>
            <TD>{{activity.aname}}</TD>
            <TD>{{activity.subprocess}}</TD>
            <TD>{{activity.cost | currency:'Rs. '}}</TD>
        </TR>
    </table>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
            <script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/mycontroller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## app/controllers/app.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
```

## app/controllers/mycontroller.js

```
    var MyC = function ($scope) {
        $scope.activities = [{aname: 'First', subprocess: 'Product', activityid: '500', cost: '2001'},
        {aname: 'Second', subprocess: 'Program', activityid: '501', cost: '1500'},
        {aname: 'Third', subprocess: 'Engineeding', activityid: '502', cost: '5999'},
        {aname: 'Fourth', subprocess: 'Resource', activityid: '503', cost: '999'},
        {aname: 'Fifth', subprocess: 'FM', activityid: '504', cost: '1765'}];
```

};

```
    angular.module('demoApp')
        .controller('MyC', MyC);
```

## Getting output as:

```
Filter it on: textbox shows here.

Activity Id Sbprocess Name  Activity Name   Cost
{{activity.activityid}} {{activity.aname}}  {{activity.subprocess}}         {{activity.cost | currency:'Rs. '}}
```

Here instead of showing 2 rows, it just displays as {{}} for all the paramaters.

please help me know the issue. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: My Array is :   $scope.activities = [{aname: 'First', subprocess: 'Product', activityid: '500', cost: '2001'},
                       {aname: 'Second', subprocess: 'Program', activityid: '501', cost: '1500'},
                       {aname: 'Third', subprocess: 'Engineeding', activityid: '502', cost: '5999'},
                       {aname: 'Fourth', subprocess: 'Resource', activityid: '503', cost: '999'},
                       {aname: 'Fifth', subprocess: 'FM', activityid: '504', cost: '1765'}];

Answer (score 2):

Remove the bad token in the array:

```
 $scope.activities = [{aname: 'First', subprocess: 'Product', activityid:     '500', cost: '2001'},
    {aname: 'Second', subprocess: 'Program', activityid: '501', cost: '1500'},
        }/*<-----remove this*/ ];
};
```

Codepen working:
http://codepen.io/armellajuan/pen/admKOv

Comment: If you are using chrome maybe is usefull to check the console for this type of errors. Just hit f12 and go to "console".

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. for simplicity, i have removed few entries while keeping in here. I dont that any bad characters in my code.

Comment: With you new array is working: http://codepen.io/armellajuan/pen/xZEpBG or i didn't undestand the problem.

Comment: No its not working. Thanks for your response. I will try with f12 though.

Comment: Maybe is a script problem. Check the console. Maybe you see an include problem.